# Way to get updates from database with SignalR (real time)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr, asp.net-mvc-5

Is there a way to get database's exist fields and new fields with SignalR?

I would like to make a multi chat application with MVC; and I would like to store all messages etc. in sql server database...

Planned rotation of the data will be client=>sql server=>client...

The technology is new or unknown so I couldn't find smart examples...

Answer (score 2):

check this article and you should be able to save all incomming messages to DB on **OnReceivedAsync** Method.

http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2013/01/22/build-a-signal-r-app-part-1.aspx

if you need to send last 20 records to any specific user or broadcast you can use below statement once you fetched last 20 records from you DB.

```
Connection.Broadcast(chatData); // this will broadcast data to all connected clients.

protected override Task OnConnectedAsync(IRequest request, string connectionId)
{
    _clients.Add(connectionId, string.Empty);
    ChatData chatData = new ChatData("Server", "A new user has joined the room.");
    return Connection.Broadcast(chatData);
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer, I think that's not solution what I asked, As simple question: how can I show last 20 sql database records records to all clients with signalr?

Comment: :) i can't see last 20 sql records requirement in above question. but in this case see my edit